# Mysql Performance issue on large table

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, mariadb

I'm having an issue with large tables on mysql.

I have more than 2.5 Million data on table. And this is my query.

```
select count(*) from location
  where tagCode=24345
    and xLocation >=81 and xLocation <=264
    and yLocation >=356 and yLocation <=484
    and locationDate >= '2017-03-08 00:00:01' and locationDate <= '2017-03-08 11:54:01';
```

I'm trying to get number of count on that query. But its fetching rows more then 1 second. And this causing problem.

I added indexes to table.

> ALTER TABLE location ADD INDEX (tagCode,xLocation,yLocation,
>   locationDate);

How Can I increase performance ?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say about this query? Does using `BETWEEN` help any?

Comment: Your query and indexes look optimal to me.If one on the other columns (e.g. locationDate) has lower cardinality then tagcode, then it might be an idea to rearrange the index accordingly.

Comment: Is the behavior consistent when executed on the DB alone?

Comment: I run query with explain and its said 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | location | index | tagCode,tagCode_2 | tagCode | 779     | NULL | 2319860 | Using where; Using index |

Comment: Have a look here. Maybe it will help: http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/

Comment: @Peter - that blog has a lot of flaws (I commented on some of them).  Plus it does not seem very applicable to this Question.

Answer (score 0):

Last thing, in my company we have 11 million of clients, so generally some cases we create a table categorized for each month, or per region.

In your case, based on LocationDate, mabe you can create a table per month too, like:

coordinator_03_2017
coodinator_02_2017

so you can do multiple threads querying at same time.

Last thing, you can do multiple querys simultaneously, separating the couting per interval, like:

Thread 1 - query1: locationDate > '2017-03-01 00:00:00'
Thread 2-  query 2: locationDate > '2017-02-01 00:00:00' and locationDate <  '2017-03-01 00:00:00'
Thread N - query N

Answer (score 0):

The x and y coordinates are hard to index.  However, this may work well, *at least for the example given*:

```
INDEX(tagCode, locationDate, xLocation, yLocation)
```

Here is the rationale:

- `tagCode` is tested with `=`; any such tests in the `WHERE` need to come first in the `INDEX`.
- Then you get *one* chance at a "range".  Since `locationDate` *seems* to be the most selective, I put it next.
- The rest of the columns are to make the index "covering".  That is, *all* the columns mentioned *anywhere* in the `SELECT` are in a single index.  This way, the query can be performed in the index BTree, without touching the Data BTree.

If you sometimes have a wide date range, but a narrow x range, then the index you added will work best.  So, keep it.  And add a third:

```
INDEX(tagCode, yLocation, locationDate, xLocation)
```

That way, the Optimizer can pick among three ranges and is likely to pick the optimal one.

Answer (score -1):

when you do '>=' are two comparision per register, try just '>'.

Another thing:

```
 locationDate >= '2017-03-08 00:00:01' and locationDate <= '2017-03-08 11:54:01'
```

I am imagining that you want a location until 'now', if i am right try just the lower condition

```
locationDate >= '2017-03-08 00:00:01'
```

More one thing, try to create isolate indexes like

```
locationDate DESC 
tagCode ASC
xLocation ASC
yLocation ASC
```

If xLocation and yLocation are declared as double, change to int like Google coordinate.

Last thing, try to put first the conditions to eliminate more number of not desired rows.

Comment: Last thing, in my company we have 11 million of clients, so generally some cases we create a table for each month.

Comment: Another extra thing?

Comment: Until now, no. If I remember something more, I will post

Comment: There is essentially no _performance_ difference between `BETWEEN`, `<=` and `<`.  Each does some form of inequality test.

Comment: `DOUBLE` vs `INT` makes essentially no difference for performance.

Comment: The order of conditions in the `WHERE` clause does _not_ matter.  The Optimizer will pick what order to do them in.

Comment: Do not mix DESC and ASC.

Comment: Do not create a table for each month -- that causes more grief than benefit.